# Top most element on ZStack is wider than screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this ZStack with a background which is wider than the device width, but I would like to put a VStack on top of that which stays within the bounds of the screen. The problem with this code is that the VStack is just as wide as the other elements in the ZStack.

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
ZStack {
    Group {
        VStack {
            Image("EmptyPhoto")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                .frame(height: 600)
            Spacer()
        }
        
        Color.black.opacity(0.5)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
        
        VStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.0)
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 0)
            
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(0.0), Color.black, Color.black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    } // Background
    
    VStack {
        Picker(selection: $filterPicker, label: EmptyView()) {
            Text("Friends").tag(1)
            Text("World").tag(2)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        
        HStack {
            Text("@gallapagos")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Spacer()
            
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: How about this: ZStack{ }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using the following:

```
extension UIScreen{
   static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
}
```

Placed this below `// Background`

```
.frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.screenWidth)
```

Comment: Do you know how to handle screen resizing with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do:

```
.frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
```